# Failed to run image. Error invoking remote method 'docker-run-container': Error: (HTTP code 400) unexpected - No command specified

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, windows-subsystem-for-linux, kuzzle

I am having trouble with docker, i had an image which i imported using the following command:

```
docker image import  C:\Users\****\Downloads\imagename-b1.tar imagename-b1:latest
```

And when i try to run image/container, for the image it gives this error:

```
Failed to run image. Error invoking remote method 'docker-run-container': Error: (HTTP code 400) unexpected - No command specified
```

And for the container it gives this error:

```
Error invoking remote method 'docker-start-container': Error: (HTTP code 400) unexpected - failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "--name": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

## Docker Version `20.10.21, build baeda1f`

I'll appreciate any suggestion.

Thank you

Comment: WIthout the Dockerfile/docker-compose.yml it's difficult to make any guess. Can you provide more details please?

Answer (score 3):

<s>Just had a similar issue.
Try starting the image from your terminal. Works for me when I did that.</s>

Can check this Github issue too.
https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/issues/1699

After using the CMD to start the image, later encountered port issues.
Found this solution that works now. https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/9272#issuecomment-776225866

TL;DR:

```
net stop winnat
```

Then start your docker container. Then

```
net start winnat
```